# Search for product titles only - WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, search, woocommerce

I have a search function that currently searches for products etc using product text and everything. I want it to search for the product titles only. I have used this code and it has worked for years, but doesn't anymore. Now I get an error. Why?

**THE CODE USED in functions.php**

```
<?php
// Search titles only 
function __search_by_title_only( $search, &$wp_query )
{
    global $wpdb;
    if(empty($search)) {
        return $search; // skip processing - no search term in query
    }
    $q = $wp_query->query_vars;
    $n = !empty($q['exact']) ? '' : '%';
    $search =
    $searchand = '';
    foreach ((array)$q['search_terms'] as $term) {
        $term = esc_sql($wpdb->esc_like($term));
        $search .= "{$searchand}($wpdb->posts.post_title LIKE '{$n}{$term}{$n}')";
        $searchand = ' AND ';
    }
    if (!empty($search)) {
        $search = " AND ({$search}) ";
        if (!is_user_logged_in())
            $search .= " AND ($wpdb->posts.post_password = '') ";
    }
    return $search;
}
add_filter('posts_search', '__search_by_title_only', 500, 2);
```

**THE ERROR**

> Warning: Parameter 2 to __search_by_title_only() expected to be a reference, value given in /customers/7/a/4/nemoko.dk/httpd.www/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php on line 286

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`function __search_by_title_only( $search, &$wp_query )`
the second parameter is start with **&** (**&$wp_query**)  that means it expects the reference variable as parameter.

`posts_search` filter passing the `WP_Query $this` object.  So just remove **`&`**  in parameter

Example:

`function __search_by_title_only( $search, $wp_query )`

Comment: @eMikkelsen just remove & symbol in function parameter and try.